# Playing with loops

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to work with loops in Python and I need a little help. The code I wrote is just something I'm playing with. It's not an assignment or anything like that.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to loop the program so that it asks the user to input something to start the questions over. This is what I have so far:

```
def monkeys():
  apes = "This is not a monkey!"
  monkey_yes = "This is a monkey!"
  is_it_a_monkey = apes + monkey_yes
  monkey_question = input("Type in Gorilla, Chimp or Macaque and make sure they're capitalized: ")

  for question in is_it_a_monkey:
    if monkey_question == 'Gorilla' or monkey_question == "Chimp":
      print(apes)
      continue
    else:
      print(monkey_yes)
      break

def main():
  while True:

    if again not in {"y","n"}:
      print("Please enter valid input")
    elif again == "n":
      return "Good bye!"
    elif again == "y":
      return monkeys()

monkeys()
```

I'm trying to get `main()` to do most of the work since that's what my teacher wants on our assignments. Everything under `main()` is something I copied to see if that would work but it only returns this:

```
Type in Gorilla, Chimp or Macaque and make sure they're capitalized: Gorilla
This is not a monkey!
This is not a monkey!
This is not a monkey!
This is not a monkey!
```

It was a lot longer than just the 4 lines but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't see that `main` is being called here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here...

First of all, you're concatenating two strings...

```
    apes = "This is not a monkey!"
    monkey_yes = "This is a monkey!"
    is_it_a_monkey = apes + monkey_yes
```

When you go into your for-loop, the interpreter is looking at each character of that concatenated string. This is why you output 38 lines of "This is not a monkey!" For what you're trying to do, you don't need a for-loop. Try this instead:

```
    def monkeys():
        apes = "This is not a monkey!"
        monkey_yes = "This is a monkey!"
        monkey_question = input("Type in Gorilla, Chimp or Macaque and make sure they're capitalized: ")

        if monkey_question == 'Gorilla' or monkey_question == "Chimp":
            print(apes)
        else:
            print(monkey_yes)
```

The next issue I see is that you don't call the main function at all. Instead of calling moneys() at the bottom of your code, call main().

Next issue is using "while True:". If you're going to use a boolean as a while condition, make sure you put logic in your code to change that condition. Changing it to "False" should be what exits your main, not a return statement. Your main() would be better off starting like this:

```
def main():
    keep_going = True
    while keep_going:
        monkeys()
```

Notice you should call your monkeys() function first, otherwise nobody will know what to input when the program starts. You also need code asking if they want to continue running the program. Right after your monkey() call, do something like this:

```
    monkeys()
    again = input("Would you like to try again? (y/n) ")
```

The next issue is your use of return statements. Instead of doing this:

```
    elif again == "n":
        return "Good bye!"
```

do this...

```
    elif again == "n":
        print("Good bye!")
        keep_going = False
```

Lastly, you have "if again not in {"y","n"}:". You have to assign a value to "again" or you'll get more errors. If you use the example above, it should meet your needs.

Keep plugging at it and don't lose hope. You're getting close to understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for making your response easy to follow. It really cleared up a lot of confusion I had with loops.

Comment: You're quite welcome. If this answers your question, please accept it as your answer. Good luck and keep on coding!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you call `monkeys()` but you should call `main()` instead since that's where the loop is. Second, `return` causes a function to halt execution and to continue where you called it. In order to continue looping, remove the `return`s in `main()`.

To get a better understanding of how your code works read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about debugging. It shows some tips that allow you to see step-by-step what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code instead, which (as many have pointed out including @Code-Apprentice above) calls the function `main()` as you intend.  @Code-Apprentice 's answer also includes a good explanation of why this works.  This code is almost exactly the same as yours above; only the last line is different:

```
def monkeys():
  apes = "This is not a monkey!"
  monkey_yes = "This is a monkey!"
  is_it_a_monkey = apes + monkey_yes
  monkey_question = input("Type in Gorilla, Chimp or Macaque and make sure they're capitalized: ")

  for question in is_it_a_monkey:
    if monkey_question == 'Gorilla' or monkey_question == "Chimp":
      print(apes)
      continue
    else:
      print(monkey_yes)
      break

def main():
  while True:

    if again not in {"y","n"}:
      print("Please enter valid input")
    elif again == "n":
      return "Good bye!"
    elif again == "y":
      return monkeys()

main()
```

The reason I am submitting this answer is to point out that, despite calling `main()`, you are going to encounter another problem right away.  You refer to a variable `again` in `main()`, but you never assign a value to `again` in the first place (if you run this code, you can expect to see an error of the form, "NameError: global name 'again' is not defined.").  Addressing this next error is beyond the scope of your question; there are lots of ways that you can re-write this code to accommodate `again`, if you choose.